# Django celery beat scheduler not working at Asia/Calcutta timezone

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, celerybeat, django-celery-beat

I am using Django celery beat with celery,

Problem which I am facing is my when I am using scheduler provided by Django-celery beat it doesn't work but using normal beat without scheduler provided by Django-celery-beat works with below command

**Doesn't works** => `celery worker --app=my_project.celery_app -l info --beat  --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler`

**Works** => `celery worker --app=my_project.celery_app -l info --beat`

one thing I noticed when I change Time_Zone to 'UTC' Django-celery-beat scheduler starts working, but i don't want to change timezone settings for djagno how do I fix this

please find my settings below

```
USE_TZ = False
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'
```

Comment: *"... when I change `Time_Zone` ....."*, Just to confirm, `TIME_ZONE` or `CELERY_TIMEZONE`?

Comment: Timezone , not celery timezone

Answer (score 1):

Can you try overriding the Database scheduler and override schedule method,
celery worker --app=my_project.celery_app -l info --beat  --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler

i have changed and data seems to show on the log file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

`celery -A my_app.celery:app beat -l info --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler`

Also, make sure you have `django_celery_beat` installed and it's added in your `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...,
    'django_celery_beat',
)
```

then `python manage.py migrate`

[here](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#beat-custom-schedulers) you can find more on the beat configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure, there must be a way to do this,

but, I would recommend you to never use tz=False in Django as every standard application is timezone aware and is using UTC as default, it doesn't matter if you are in India or any other country

Hope it makes your application better if you face any error with UTC feel free to ask here

PS. even if you want to check out other library, do look into below library

https://pypi.org/project/django-celery/